# Render texture using Cocos 2d and Box 2d

Tags: iphone, cocos2d-iphone, box2d

I have a Cocos2d and Box2D application. I have a image bubble.png. I want to draw a chain of bubbles when the user swipes the screen.

Can anyone tell me how to do this ?

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
- (void)ccTouchesMoved:(NSSet *)touches withEvent:(UIEvent *)event{
{
        //Add a new body/atlas sprite at the touched location
        for( UITouch *touch in touches ) {

            CGPoint location = [touch locationInView: [touch view]];
            location = [[CCDirector sharedDirector] convertToGL: location];

            b2Vec2 locationWorld = b2Vec2(location.x/PTM_RATIO, location.y/PTM_RATIO);

            CCSprite *mist=[CCSprite spriteWithFile:@"bubble.png"];
            mist.position=ccp(location.x,location.y);

            [self addChild:mist];
        }
}
```

Comment: What all classes do I need to import. Currently cocos2d.h is the only class imported.

Comment: #import "Box2D.h"
#import "GLES-Render.h"

Comment: yes I got to get that worked. Thanks. But my ccTouchesMoved event is not getting called when I swipe on the screen. Any ideas ?

Comment: no.. you have answered just the import question. I have implemented as you suggested but the ccTouchesMoved event is not getting called. also I get error:  
"Assigning to 'CGPoint' (aka 'CGPoint') from incompatible type 'b2Vec2'" on line " mist.position=locationWorld;
 "

Comment: mist.position=ccp(location.x,location.y);

Comment: @madhu- Is it somehow possible that I render bubble.png only once per centimeter or just one per inch ?

Comment: [self schedule:@selector(startMists) interval:2];//2seconds

Comment: when u want to stop this   [self unschedule:@selector(startMists)];

Comment: startmist is function where u add ur sprite bubble.sorry i am in production.later.if u have more doubt then go to iphone/ipad chat room for instant help.

Answer (score 0):

You need to register with the touchdispatcher I think... ( [layer registerWithTouchDispatcher] )

[glView setMultipleTouchEnabled:YES]; (Maybe this is needed for swiping)